GitLab Runner with Virtualbox executor cannot handle concurrent jobs
I would like to run 2 (more than 1) jobs concurrently with my preconfigured virtualbox executor (Windows 10 base image). The Virtualbox creates two instances of my base image (xyz-concurrent-0 and xyz-concurrent-1), and starting the jobs together, and the runner get them up, the first one works correctly, but the second one always fails with the following error message:
Log of the job which started a bit earlier:
Running with gitlab-runner 16.10.0 (81ab07f6)
  on Runner_1 93V7Dm8Bk, system ID: s_a1f2f83ac892
Preparing the "virtualbox" executor
01:55
Using VirtualBox version 7.0.14r161095 executor...
Creating new VM...
Creating default snapshot...
Waiting for VM to become responsive...
Starting SSH command...
Preparing environment
00:02
Running on WIN10 via 
EVH11716WS...
Getting source from Git repository
00:12
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/gitlab-user/builds/myname/roli-dummy-project/.git/
Created fresh repository.
warning: auto-detection of host provider took too long (>2000ms)
warning: see https://aka.ms/gcm/autodetect for more information.
fatal: Unable to persist credentials with the 'wincredman' credential store.
See https://aka.ms/gcm/credstores for more information.
Checking out 6cce2e68 as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
git-lfs/3.4.1 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.20.11; git 0898dcbc)
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:32
$ powershell -File echo.ps1
WIN10
WIN10
WIN10
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded

Log of the job which started a bit later:
Running with gitlab-runner 16.10.0 (81ab07f6)
  on Runner_1 93V7Dm8Bk, system ID: s_a1f2f83ac892
Preparing the "virtualbox" executor
00:25
Using VirtualBox version 7.0.14r161095 executor...
Creating new VM...
ERROR: Preparation failed: VBoxManageOutput error: vboxmanage.exe: error: Locking of attached media failed. A possible reason is that one of the media is attached to a running VM
vboxmanage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using VirtualBox version 7.0.14r161095 executor...
Restoring VM from snapshot...
Previous VM failed. Deleting, because VBoxManageOutput error: 
Creating new VM...
ERROR: Preparation failed: VBoxManageOutput error: vboxmanage.exe: error: Locking of attached media failed. A possible reason is that one of the media is attached to a running VM
vboxmanage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using VirtualBox version 7.0.14r161095 executor...
Restoring VM from snapshot...
Previous VM failed. Deleting, because VBoxManageOutput error: 
Creating new VM...
ERROR: Preparation failed: VBoxManageOutput error: vboxmanage.exe: error: Locking of attached media failed. A possible reason is that one of the media is attached to a running VM
vboxmanage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): VBoxManageOutput error: vboxmanage.exe: error: Locking of attached media failed. A possible reason is that one of the media is attached to a running VM
vboxmanage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine

I have tried out different configurations, such as:

one runner with 2 concurrent jobs allowed (this is the setup which has the given logs, but the other one has the same response)

concurrent = 2
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Runner_1"
  url = "myurl"
  id = 1
  token = "mytoken"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-04-19T10:36:11Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "virtualbox"
  shell = "powershell"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "gitlab-user"
    identity_file = "C:\\Users\\myuser\\.ssh\\id_ed25519"
    disable_strict_host_key_checking = true
  [runners.virtualbox]
    base_name = "Win10_prepare"
    base_folder = ""
    disable_snapshots = false
    start_type = ""


two runners with 2 concurrent jobs allowed

concurrent = 2
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Runner_1"
  url = "myurl"
  id = 1
  token = "mytoken"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-04-19T10:36:11Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "virtualbox"
  shell = "powershell"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "gitlab-user"
    identity_file = "C:\\Users\\myuser\\.ssh\\id_ed25519"
    disable_strict_host_key_checking = true
  [runners.virtualbox]
    base_name = "Win10_prepare"
    base_folder = ""
    disable_snapshots = false
    start_type = ""

[[runners]]
  name = "Runner_2"
  url = "myurl"
  id = 2
  token = "mytoken"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-04-19T10:36:11Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "virtualbox"
  shell = "powershell"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "gitlab-user"
    identity_file = "C:\\Users\\myuser\\.ssh\\id_ed25519"
    disable_strict_host_key_checking = true
  [runners.virtualbox]
    base_name = "Win10_prepare"
    base_folder = ""
    disable_snapshots = false
    start_type = ""


Based on the error message, have you got the installation media for the VM still mounted as a disk on the image? It seems like it's VirtualBox failing here.

@Nanhydrin yes, the base image has its disk mounted. But I don't understand, why it isn't a problem with the first job :( The Win10_prepare base VM is shutted down

I must have misunderstood, but I thought your post said that both the setup with one runner, and two runners, both produced the same issue?

When you say the second job starts "a bit later", how much later do you mean?

@Nanhydrin yes, both of the setups gives the same output.
I started the 1st job, then clicked on the other browser tab and started the second.

All I can suggest at the moment is that job number 2 is trying to spin up a second VM, and that second VM can't start because VM1 has the installation media file locked. I would try unmounting from the base image and then running again to see what happens. The other option is that if you think that the VM should be shut down after job 1, then something must be keeping it open so the second VM can't be spun up, but the I think it would be for the same file lock reason .

@Nanhydrin I will try this out tomorrow, and comment the results. Thanks for your suggestions!
